# Customize QTreeView items

Tags: python, qt, customization, pyside, qtreeview

I'm new to PySide and Qt at all, and now need to create an application which has a tree view with styled items. Each item needs two lines of text (different styles), and a button. Many items are supposed to be in the view, so I chose QTreeView over QTreeWidget. Now I managed to add simple text items (non-styled) to the QTreeView and have almost no idea about how to place several widgets on one item. Could you please give me an example of how to create such design?

I've found some samples on the Internet, that are similar to what I want, but they all are in C++, and it's not obvious how to convert delegates and other things to Python. I'm now really confused about it all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recomend you use simple `QTreeWidget` and insert complex widgets with `setItemWidget`. While Qt's widhets are *alien*, they are not so heavy to draw, but:

- You shouldn't create delegates.
- You shouldn't handle events (If you are going to place button in view and draw it using delegates, you had to handle *all* its events, such as *mouseOver*, *focus changing*, etc. It is *a lot* of work.

Comment: Using `setItemWidget` it's possible to set one widget for item. And how to have several QLabels and a QPushButton at each item? There should be something like QPanel, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @chersanya, first, you are able to set separate widget for every column, then your widget can have very complicated internal structure.

Comment: @Lol4to and how to make "very complicated internal structure" of my widget?

Comment: @chersanya, same way as you usually create GUI. You can even create form in UI designer and pass this form as a widget.

Comment: @Lol4to, now I load UI using `QUiLoader().load('form.ui')`. Could you give an example of how to use similar construction for adding widget (from .ui file) to `QTreeWidget` and set text on widget labels?

Comment: @chersanya, `list->setItemWidget(item, column, QUiLoader().load('form.ui'))`. `load` method just return `QWidget`. You can operate _as usual_